# How can I stop "screen_view" event on specific ViewController

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

If you create a screen by overlaying ViewController using `addChild()`.
When you display the child screen, parent `screen_view` also happens.

I saw this, but I do not know how to actually fix it.
[Firebase Screen Tracking calls "screen_view" event twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46931632/firebase-screen-tracking-calls-screen-view-event-twice)

Thank you.